# Caseless matching using views in Cloudant

Tags: regex, cloudant

I have a database of documents that have the following data structure:

```
{
    "_id": "sampleID",
    "_rev": "sample-rev",
    "added": "2014-09-09 01:05:32",
    "cached": 1,
    "subject": "sample topic",
    "mode": "<samplemode>",
    "protected": 0,
    "added_by": "myname",
    "factoid": "sample factoid"
}
```

And I have the following view:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.subject && doc.factoid && doc.mode){
        emit(doc.subject, doc.factoid);
    }
}
```

I need to retrieve all docs where the "subject" matches a provided key.  I would like it to be non case sensitive.  The POST will give me all of the matches I want, but only if the case matches.

```
https://<username>.cloudant.com/<db>/_design/<designdoc>/_view/<view>?include_docs=true

{ "keys" : ["<subject>"] }
```

I have also tried search indexes without success.  This API mentions a regex operator that I haven't been able to get working.  It seems like a simple thing, how should I be approaching this?

Regarding the $regex approach, here is where I'm at.  The following POST works much like my previous attempts at returning case-sensitive results.

```
https://<username>.cloudant.com/<db>/_find

{
    "selector": {
        "subject": {"$eq": "<subject>"}
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "subject", "factoid"]
}
```

Substituting a $regex operator for the $eq yields the following error:

```
{
"error": "no_usable_index",
"reason": "There is no operator in this selector can used with an index."
}
```

The reference material for this function is rather slim.  It is only mentioned on this page: https://docs.cloudant.com/api/cloudant-query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a secondary index that stores the uppercased search string:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.subject){
        emit(doc.subject.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

The application can then uppercase the search criteria before sending it to the database:

```
https://username.cloudant.com/database/_design/designdoc/_view/view?key=“SAMPLE TOPIC"&include_docs=true
```

Will result in this:

```
{
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "doc": {
                "_id": "sampleID",
                "_rev": "1-d77a468b74497771f8d37130a7cf02eb",
                "added": "2014-09-09 01:05:32",
                "added_by": "myname",
                "cached": 1,
                "factoid": "sample factoid",
                "mode": "<samplemode>",
                "protected": 0,
                "subject": "sample topic"
            },
            "id": "sampleID",
            "key": "SAMPLE TOPIC",
            "value": null
        }
    ],
    "total_rows": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think using the Cloudant Query $regex operator is the way to go.

The reason you received that error when you subbed it in was because you cannot use $regex as the base of your selector expression. Here are the relevant bits from their documentation (https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#condition-operators):

> However, not all operators can be used as the base or starting point of the selector expression.
>
> You cannot use combination or array logical operators such as $regex as the basis of a query.

So instead, you could do something like:

```
https://<username>.cloudant.com/<db>/_find

{
    "selector": {
        "_id": {
            "$gt": null
        },
        "subject": {"$regex": "<subject>"}
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "subject", "factoid"]
}
```

This should give you the result you are looking for, however, the documentation does go on to say the following, so be careful on large databases:

> This expression is always true, enabling the remainder of the selector expression to be applied.
>
> Using {"_id": { "$gt":null } } induces a full-table scan, and is not efficient for large databases.

Comment: The URL for $regex documentation has changed, here you go: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#combination-operators